# How to remove blank lines within a cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiline text in a single Excel cell. I want to remove all blank lines from that text.  I must be clear that I do not want to remove all line breaks.

**Example A:**

```
There is a place where the sidewalk ends
And before the street begins,
And there the grass grows soft and white,

And there the sun burns crimson bright,
And there the moon-bird rests from his flight

To cool in the peppermint wind.
```

...should translate to:

```
There is a place where the sidewalk ends
And before the street begins,
And there the grass grows soft and white,
And there the sun burns crimson bright,
And there the moon-bird rests from his flight
To cool in the peppermint wind.
```

**Example B:**

```
There is a place where the sidewalk ends
And before the street begins,
And there the grass grows soft and white,
And there the sun burns crimson bright,
And there the moon-bird rests from his flight

To cool in the peppermint wind.
```

...should translate to:

```
There is a place where the sidewalk ends
And before the street begins,
And there the grass grows soft and white,
And there the sun burns crimson bright,
And there the moon-bird rests from his flight
To cool in the peppermint wind.
```

I want to remove blank lines because:

- Viewing the spreadsheet, it may look like some cells are empty, but in reality they *do* have text after several empty lines;
- I need to clean the data for import into another storage solution

Microsoft has some documentation on how to remove spaces in Excel.

But it does not specifically describe a solution for removing blank lines:

- [CLEAN function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/clean-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41)
- [TRIM function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/trim-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9)
- [Top ten ways to clean your data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/top-ten-ways-to-clean-your-data-2844b620-677c-47a7-ac3e-c2e157d1db19)

Comment: Are the blank lines always empty, or do they contain spaces occasionally?

Comment: If just blank lines, something like `=SUBSTITUTE(A1, CONCATENATE(CHAR(13),CHAR(10),CHAR(13),CHAR(10)),CONCATENATE(CHAR(13),CHAR(10)))`  where `A1` is the cell you want to process.

Comment: Only problem with the above is it does not catch multiple blank lines, it could be applied multiple times to catch that, though that is limited in straight formulas.  Otherwise regex would be nice, though that is not built in to Excel annoyingly, so would need a bit of VBA.

Comment: @Orbling Microsoft does support a Regular Expressions library.

Comment: @DavidZemens: Yes, I know that - but there are no built in Excel Functions for regular expression use.  You have to expose them via VBA from the relevant library.

Comment: If the text string is located in Cell A1, you can insert the following array formula in any cell you wish to have only the blank carriage lines removed. =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)&"",CHAR(10)&"^"),CHAR(10)&"^"&CHAR(10)&"^","%"),"%",CHAR(10))   [Ctrl,Shift & Enter Keys]

Answer (score 3):

VBA Solution:

```
Sub DoubleReturn()
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "", Replacement:="" & Chr(10) & ""
End Sub
```

---

Non-VBA solution:

In your find box: ALT+0010 (Twice) for two carriage returns.

In your replace box: ALT+0010 (Once)

Answer (score 3):

Excel does have some regex support, you just need some crazy VBA to use it.  I tested this a little and it seems to work.

Just put this in a module and you should be able to use cell formulas like `=ClearLineBreaks(A1)`.

```
Function ClearLineBreaks(txt As String)
    Application.Volatile
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "(\r|\n) ?"
        .Global = True
        ClearLineBreaks = Trim(.Replace(txt, " "))
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Well you will notice that I did say it requires VBA - not that it was not present, I meant not available in regular functions.  Note you want to adapt this to clear only **double** line breaks, not single.